# How to put object into string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, object

When a used click an image, I want to put this clicked image into lightbox. That's working.
I would like to add another functionality and next to the displayed image in lightbox, I would like to put there a form yet.

```
var aaa = $(this).addClass("some_class");
aaa.modal();
```

This is working well. The images is displayed in the lightbox correctly.

Further,

```
var aaa = $(this).addClass("instagram_modal_active");
var modal_data = $('#show').html('<div class="modal"><div class="left">xx</div><div class="right">sfaf sf</div></div>');

modal_data.modal();
```

This is working correctly as well - in the lightbox window are displayed 2 columns with some text.

Now, I would like to put into the left column the clicked image:

```
var aaa = $(this).addClass("instagram_modal_active");
var modal_data = $('#show').html('<div class="modal"><div class="left">'+aaa.html()+'</div><div class="right">sfaf sf</div></div>');

modal_data.modal();
```

or

```
var modal_data = $('#show').html('<div class="modal"><div class="left">'+aaa+'</div><div class="right">sfaf sf</div></div>');
```

But in both cases the clicked image is not displayed inside the mini-layout of lightbox.

Regarding to "error" messages - I am getting errors like `[object Object]` or displaying the image outside the lightbox.

Could I ask you guys for advice on how to put the image with another text?

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: in the last code snippet you are putting the object 'aaa' directly into the html string. This will give faulty output.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I fixed it this way:

```
var aaa = $(this).addClass("some_class");
var modal_data = $('#show').html('<div class="modal"><div class="left"></div><div class="right">sfaf sf</div></div>');
$('.left').html(aaa);    

modal_data.modal();
```

Everything seems to be working.